# How to open the sdcard.img file on windows?

Tags: android, gestures

I use the Gesture Build to build some gestures for my app on the Emulator. The generated file is saved in the sdcard, which on my Windows is a img file. How can I load it and get the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use adb to get files from your emulator.For example if the file is in the root of the sdcard then

> adb pull /mnt/sdcard/filename.ext